# APIGEE in GCP Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apigee

We have a current project: pj-xyz-dev
We would also probably require a pj-abc-dev, pj-ghi-prod , pj-czi-prod.

We need to check how easy it is to attach these to the respective APIGEE environments for the Logging capabilities.

And how to transport the confirmation from one environment/project to another on GCP?

We want to check the standard out of the box capabilities between APIGEE and GCP